# Installing Magento 2 after installing Composer: Vendor Autoload Error

Tags: php, magento, composer-php

I am trying to install Magento 2 multistore and I have installed composer but still, I am getting this error.

> Vendor autoload is not found.
> Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Vendor-autoload-is-not-found-Please-run-composer-install-under/td-p/82767

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have installed the `composer` command, but you did not actually run the command `composer install` in your [terminal](https://www.quora.com/In-coding-terms-what-is-a-terminal-and-what-is-it-used-for).

This will install all your dependencies.

You should probably read the documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).